# Утечка памяти в leveldb?

Tags: c++, qt5, c++11

Делаю **простейшую** программу, которая в таймере записывает по одному рекорду в базу leveldb. Проблема в том, что постоянно растет память. Баг leveldb или сделанно что-то неправильно?

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

#include <QTimer>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QtEndian>
#include <QDebug>


//класс Комператора
class LittleIndianComparator : public leveldb::Comparator
{
public:
    int Compare(const leveldb::Slice& a, const leveldb::Slice& b) const {

        quint64 akey, bkey, aval, bval;

        QDataStream(QByteArray(a.data(), 8)) >> aval;
        QDataStream(QByteArray(b.data(), 8)) >> bval;

        qToBigEndian(aval, (uchar*)&akey);
        qToBigEndian(bval, (uchar*)&bkey);

        return (akey > bkey) ? -1 : (akey < bkey) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    // Ignore the following methods for now:
    const char* Name() const { return "LittleIndianComparator"; }
    void FindShortestSeparator(std::string*, const leveldb::Slice&) const { }
    void FindShortSuccessor(std::string*) const { }
};
//========================================================================
//В классе окна у нас основная логика

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    _timer(nullptr)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    leveldb::Options options;
    options.comparator = new LittleIndianComparator();
    options.create_if_missing = true;
    leveldb::Status status = leveldb::DB::Open(options, "/home/rishat/Test", &db);

    write_options.sync = true;

    _timer = new QTimer(this);
    //таймер для переодического вызова записи в базу
    connect(_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(on_test1Button_clicked()));

    //TODO: status
    qDebug() << "STATUS" << status.ToString().data();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

//тут мы записываем в базу 1 запись
void MainWindow::on_test1Button_clicked()
{
    //тут мы записываем в базу 1 запись
    static int counter = 0;
    qint64 msecs = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();

    uchar key[sizeof(qint64)];
    memset(key,0,sizeof(key));

    qToLittleEndian( msecs, key );

    char arr[350];;
    arr[349] = 0;
    memset(arr,'b',349);//будет записанно 349 литер 'b' 

    leveldb::Status status = db->Put(write_options, leveldb::Slice(reinterpret_cast<char*>(key),sizeof(key)) , leveldb::Slice(arr,349) );

    if (counter % 100 == 0) { //выводит счетчик записей
        qDebug() << "STATUS" << status.ToString().data();
        qDebug() << "counter" << counter;
        ui->infoLabel->setText(QString("Counter: ") + QString::number(counter));
    }



    counter++;
}

//Тут вызываем таймер для переодической записи в базу
void MainWindow::on_testTestButton_clicked()
{
    //вызываем таймер для переодической записи
    _timer->start(1);//Будем записывать 1 запись каждую тысячную долю секунды (по возможности)
    ui->infoLabel->setText("Start");
    ui->stopTestButton->setEnabled(true);
    ui->testTestButton->setEnabled(false);
}

void MainWindow::on_stopTestButton_clicked()
{
    _timer->stop();
    ui->infoLabel->setText("Stop");
    ui->stopTestButton->setEnabled(false);
    ui->testTestButton->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Память растет только во время записи. Тестировал на **Ubuntu 15.10**. Установленные пакеты для leveldb:

```
libleveldb-dev:amd64                install
libleveldb1v5:amd64             install
```

Содержимое файла .pro

```
QT       += core gui

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

unix:!macx: LIBS += -lleveldb

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/leveldb

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = testleveldb
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        MainWindow.cpp

HEADERS  += MainWindow.h

FORMS    += MainWindow.ui
```

Comment: запустите с помощью valgrind и посмотрите.

Comment: Предположу, что проблема в `options.comparator = new LittleIndianComparator();` - память выделяете, но потом не освобождаете

Comment: @Pavel Parshin объект создается только один раз в конструкторе, течет в таймере, то есть при записи

Comment: @KoVadim **valgrind** не показывает никаких внутренних ошибок, если подключить External Errors, то показывает кучу потерь, у которых начало в самом Qt либо в линуксовых библиотек ("возможная" потеря). Ни одну libleveldb не заметил. Но ведь память растет, зараза! И прямо пропорционально сделанным записям (то есть на медленном компе меньше, так как не успевает за 1/1000 сек записать). Не баг, а фича?

Comment: Есть мысль, что Вы неверно измеряете "утечку памяти". Я бы на ночь оставил бы, пусть работает. Если к утру упадет от нехватки памяти - точно течет.

Comment: @KoVadim да, уже оставлял на выходные - растет. Часок подождал сегодня, на мегабайт выросла (в расчетное время). Сейчас на двух компах сравниваю скорость роста, похоже, что ~пропорционально количеству записанных записей (Падать не падает, но растет, измерял htop'ом, а потом (для большей точности (т.к. htop в мегах)) top'ом.